# Issue to show value in dropdown list and user entered input field value is not cleared when clicked on submit button - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with html and jQuery. I am iterating the json values when user click on submit button and show in the html table.
I have **issue to show the value in the "mortgageType" dropdown list**, whereas loanNum and Status fields are shown as expected when user clicked on submit button. 
**Another issue** is when user enters the data in 1st row and 3rd row and click on submit button, i want to clear the data 
entered by the user and show the new values which i got from the backend.

**Note:** Only Mortgage Type column is the editable field where user can select the value from drop down and enter some text in the text field available in that column.

Example :

```
var mortageType = [{"code":"Home","description":"Home"},{"code":"Car","description":"Car"}];
var loanNum = [{"code":"23432","description":"23432"},{"code":"33333","description":"33333"}];
```

In the above json variables, i'm getting two rows of data which i want to show in the first two rows. 
When the page loaded if user entered the data in 1st row and 3rd row and click on submit button, the above json values 
are shown in the first two rows but the 3rd row data which user entered is not cleared in the text field available in the
Mortgage Type column but the dropdown list value is cleared as expected. Below is the code i have tried to reset the user entered values
when user click on submit button.

```
$('#loanTable input).val('');     
$('.mortgageType').val('');
```

Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/4bHYIEybwcofvw1uMzzI?p=preview

example code:

```
function submitData(){
        var flag = true;
        $('#loanTable input[type="text"]').val('');
        $('.mortgageType').val(''); 
        if (flag) {
          //values from backend
            var mortageType = [{"code":"Home","description":"Home"},{"code":"Car","description":"Car"}];
            var loanNum = [{"code":"23432","description":"23432"},{"code":"33333","description":"33333"}];
            var status = [{"code":"Approved","description":"Approved"},{"code":"Pending","description":"Pending"}];
               var j = 0;
              //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 when user click on submit button
            for(var i=0; i<mortageType.length; i++){
                  j= j + 1;
               var mortageTypeValue = document.getElementById("mortageType"+j);
              console.log(" mortageType[i].code "+ mortageType[i].code);
              mortageTypeValue.innerHTML = mortageType[i].code;
                 var loanNumVal = document.getElementById("loanNum"+j);
                loanNumVal.innerHTML = loanNum[i].code;
                 var statusVal = document.getElementById("status"+j);
                statusVal.innerHTML = status[i].code;
           }
         } 
    }
```

html code:

```
<table class="loanTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="3765" maxlength="1"class="message">Year</span></label> </th> <!-- From Dealer -->
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="568" maxlength="1" class="message">Mortgage Type</span>&nbsp;
            <span name="496" maxlength="1" class="message"></span>
        </label>
        </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="3702" maxlength="1" class="message">Loan Num</span></label> </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="2366" maxlength="1" class="message">Status</span></label> </th>
        <th>    <label for="show"><span name="179"  maxlength="1" class="message">Comments</span></label> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
            <select id="year" name="year" disabled>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="cloneX10 indField">
                <label for="show" class="ddownlabels"></label> <!-- From Dealer -->
                <select id="mortageType1" name="mortageType1" class="mortgageType">
                  <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Auto">Auto</option>
                    <option value="Home">Home</option>
                    <option value="Car">Car</option>
                </select>
                <input name="ord1">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="loanNum1"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="status1"></div></td>
        <td><div class="cloneX10 indField" id="comments1"></div></td>
    </tr>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example I don't see any code for clear that value.

```
<input name="ord1">
```

You need to give an id to this input box and then clear the box with `innerHTML`

for `mortageTypeValue` you need to use `SelectedIndex` instead of `innerHTML`

**Update**

I'm not sure if is this what you want but try with this:

```
    function submitData() {
        var flag = true;
        $('#loanTable input[type="text"]').val('');
        $('.mortgageType').val('');
        if (flag) {
            //values from backend
            var mortageType = [{ "code": "Home", "description": "Home" }, { "code": "Car", "description": "Car" }];
            var loanNum = [{ "code": "23432", "description": "23432" }, { "code": "33333", "description": "33333" }];
            var status = [{ "code": "Approved", "description": "Approved" }, { "code": "Pending", "description": "Pending" }];
            var j = 0;
            //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 when user click on submit button
            for (var i = 0; i < mortageType.length; i++) {
                j = j + 1;
                console.log(" mortageType[i].code " + mortageType[i].code);
                document.getElementById("mortageType" + j).value = mortageType[i].code;
                document.getElementById("ord" + j).value = "";
                document.getElementById("loanNum" + j).innerText = loanNum[i].code;
                document.getElementById("status" + j).innerText = status[i].code;
            }
            document.getElementById("ord3").value = "";
        }
    }
```

And in the HTML change those lines:

```
<input id="ord1" name="ord1">
<input id="ord2" name="ord2">
<input id="ord3" name="ord3">
```

I hope it is what you are looking for, if not please clarify your requirement.

Comment: Please see edited plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/TKJRhuLX2SKh0s2FXFSM?p=preview . I have used $('#loanTable input[type="text"]').val(''); to clear the text value entered in the input fields (not working). I want to show the dynamic value in the dropdown list when user click on submit button as the selected option. I have used selectedIndex as you mentioned above but still it is not showing me the dynamic value shown in "var mortageType" json variable..Any inputs would be helpful..thanks.@user2272143

Comment: What option you want to select? as I see in your code you try to set the value of  mortageType[0].code for this just use document.getElementById("mortageType" + j).value = mortageType[0].code;

Comment: Your question is not clear because you want on submit to set the value of the select to a value that you get from json variables? Why then you use a select if you don't get the users input?